# How can I improve ARIMA model performance for monthly sales forecasting with only 12 rows of data for each of the 100 products?

Tags: data-science, arima, sarimax

I have a dataset of 100 different products and their monthly sales respectively.  My goal is to forecast the monthly sales of the products accurately. By eye-glancing the data I observed the sales for each product were different and I believed making a single ARIMA model for all the products will have poor generalization. That's why I decided to make ARIMA models for each product.

Sadly I have data for only one year which gives me only 12 rows for training and testing for each product (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBG6c.png). I tried making an ARIMA model but the computed 'd'(Differencing) value was poor (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYd9D.png).  I am still learning the time forecasting model. What should be my next course of action?